# How do i concat the values of select and input field and also display altogether with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, select, input, innerhtml, concatenation

I'm making a phone picker input menu which has a `<select>` and `<input>` field just like below:

```
<select id="country">
    <option data-countryCode="IN" value="91">India</option>
    <option data-countryCode="US" value="1">US</option>
    <option data-countryCode="GB" value="44">UK</option>
</select>
```

```
<input type="tel" placeholder ="956 826 4457" id="tel">
```

JS code:

```
 const select = document.querySelector('#country');
    const tel = document.getElementById('tel')
        tel.value = `${select.options[select.selectedIndex].value}` +`${tel.value}`
```

How do I concat/join the `select` value with the `input` field and also display whole together in that input field.

Comment: What issue are you having right now?

Comment: @palaSH 
1) I want to set the input value to selected value of  `select tag + the input value ` 
in short i want `final input value of  id="tel" == select value + input value `
2) Display the final value in a input field

Comment: Yes, I get it but what error are you getting when you use the code you have shared?

Comment: NO error. it just renders the input value which i type in the input field not the select value all together .
like i want the final Input field value to be as select value + typed input value and also possibly display altogether  in that same field.
I tried an adding eventlistner to it
```
`tel.addEventListener('input', function input(){`
`            tel.value = `${select.options[select.selectedIndex].value}` +`${tel.value}``
    `    })`
```
But it way rendering something really ugly and string was becoming too long in just few input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this

```js
const select = document.querySelector('#country');
const tel = document.getElementById('tel');
let prevVal = select.value; // storing previous value of select

// this block will be exected on init of code
if(tel.value) tel.value = `${select.value}${tel.value}`;
else tel.placeholder = `${select.value}${tel.placeholder}`;

// adding event on changing input
tel.addEventListener('change', ({ target }) => {
  const reg = new RegExp(`(^${prevVal} )`);
  // checking do we already have country code
  if (reg.test(target.value)) tel.value = tel.value.replace(reg, target.value);
  else tel.value = `${select.value}${target.value}`;
});

// adding event on changing select
select.addEventListener('change', ({ target }) => {
  const reg = new RegExp(`(^${prevVal})`);
  if(tel.value) tel.value = `${target.value}${tel.value.replace(reg, '')}`;
  else tel.placeholder =  tel.placeholder.replace(reg, target.value);
  prevVal = target.value;
});
```

```html
<select id="country">
    <option data-countryCode="IN" value="91" selected>India</option>
    <option data-countryCode="US" value="1">US</option>
    <option data-countryCode="GB" value="44">UK</option>
</select>

<input type="tel" placeholder ="956 826 4457" id="tel">
```

Comment: hey Georgiy, I'm trying to implement your code in my react project but it is giving out some issue. could you please help me. I'm trying for hours long but still I'm not getting how to solve it. [the issue is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61011080/whats-the-proper-way-of-selecting-selectedoption-of-select-tag-in-react)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have put a '-' instead of an '=' sign on the first line. It should be:

```
<select id="country">
```

Also, why have you used jQuery? Javascript covers it just as easily:

```
const select = document.getElementById('country');
const tel = document.getElementById('tel');
tel.value = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value + tel.value;
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all there are some wierd details in the code you provided.

```
<select id-"country">
```

supposes to be

```
<select id="country">
```

?

2. why do you concat templates with plus using templates at the same time? isn't it enough just to use

   tel.value = `${select.options[select.selectedIndex].value}${tel.value}`

?

In addition, what event are you going to use? If we select country for the first time it works well, adding '91' for example. But next time (if we picked up the wrong country accidentally) it will add the code again.

As for the problem , could you give more detailed explanation of what happens now exactly

Comment: NO error. it just renders the input value which i type in the input field not the select value all together .
like i want the final Input field value to be as select value + typed input value and also possibly display altogether  in that same field.
I tried an adding eventlistner to it
```
`tel.addEventListener('input', function input(){`
`            tel.value = `${select.options[select.selectedIndex].value}` +`${tel.value}``
    `    })`
```
But it way rendering something really ugly and string was becoming too long in just few input